# symfony 1.4 - doctrine - relationships in model schema

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

am trying to create one to many relation, below is my yml sechma

```
Country:
    actAs:
        Timestampable: ~
        I18n:
            fields: [country_name]
    columns:
        country_code: { type: string(30), notnull:true, unique: true }
        country_name: { type: string(200), notnull:true }
        country_flag: { type: string(200), notnull: flase }
        created_by: {type: bigint, notnull: true }
        updated_by: {type: bigint, notnull: false }
    relations:
        sfGuardUser1: { local: created_by, foreign: id, class: sfGuardUser }
        sfGuardUser2: { local: updated_by, foreign: id, class: sfGuardUser }
City: 
    actAs: 
        Timestampable: ~
        I18n: 
            fields: [city_name]
    columns:
        city_name: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
        country_code: { type: integer, notnull: true }
        created_by: {type: bigint, notnull: true }
        updated_by: {type: bigint, notnull: false }        
    relations: 
        Country:
            local: country_code
            foreign: country_code
            class: Country
        sfGuardUser1: { local: created_by, foreign: id, class: sfGuardUser }
        sfGuardUser2: { local: updated_by, foreign: id, class: sfGuardUser }
```

the problem am facing is with the sql generated. The above yml is building a constraint on both table meanwhile I only want the constraint to be built for City table. Any idea how can I do that?

Regards,

Comment: What constraints are you talking about?

Comment: You have "unique: true" in your country_code column for the Country table....?

Comment: Is this foreign key constraints? If so, you can only get rid of them by manually managing the relationship in your models and leaving it out of the schema.

Comment: Do you maybe mean to make country_code the primary key for the Country table? Making it unique isn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `foreign` to `id`, because by default Doctrine considers primary keys called `id` until you set it manually in schema. Also, I would manually set relation type in schema (or in model, as mentioned by @benlumney):

```
relations: 
    Country:
        local: country_code
        foreign: id # or you can just skip this param in this case
        class: Country
        type: many
        foreignType: one
```